# Laravel Tests Database Doesn't Roll Back

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am trying to run CI tests with Laravel. The tests always fail, however, as the database doesn't appear to be rolled back after each test. This leads to errors such as the following:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'user_roles' already exists (SQL: create table `user_roles` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `user_id` int unsigned not null, `role_id` int unsigned not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)
```

I tried some code I found on the internet, which uses the `DatabaseMigrations` trait on the test class, which works fine for the first test, but doesn't work for the rest of them:

```php
/**
* Set up the environment for testing.
*/
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->runDatabaseMigrations();

    // Create an example user
    $this->user = new User();
    $this->user->name = 'Test User';
    $this->user->email = 'test@example.com';
    $this->user->password = '';
    $this->user->save();
}
```

And even tried adding a `migrate:rollback` call to the `tearDown` method of the tests, to no avail:

```php
public function tearDown()
{
    parent::tearDown();
    $this->artisan('migrate:rollback');
}
```

Any ideas as to how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just after posting this question, I looked at the migrations, as I had realised there were a couple tables being migrated in before my `user_roles` table. This was when I noticed that the `down` function removed the foreign keys from the table, but didn't drop it:

```php
/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('user_roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('user_roles_user_id_foreign');
        $table->dropForeign('user_roles_role_id_foreign');
    });
}
```

Adding `Schema::drop('user_roles');` to the `down` method, drops it after each test, and allows the rest of the tests after the initial one to function as intended.